# How to convert time from local timezone into Sydney timezone using korn shell?

Tags: shell, timezone

I need to convert time from localtimezone (CET/CEST) to Sydney timezone (AEDT/AEST). I tried something like this:

```
export date=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S AEDT")
date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z" -d "$date"
```

It doesn't work, it doesn't recognize "AEDT", however I tried this with "UTC" and it worked. I tried to replace "AEDT" with "Australia/Sydney" (I found it in /usr/share/zoneinfos), but result was the same.

I would appreciate any advices, I am using korn shell. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
TZ=Australia/Sydney date ...
```

**Output**

```
Sat  1 Nov 2014 02:24:37 AEDT
```

Comment: Now get some sleep :-)